# "Sharing of knowledge" vs. "knowledge sharing"

Tags: word-choice, titles, modifier-vs-of

As the title of a scoping document for a major project, which is better?

> - Delivering mutual benefit
>     through sharing of knowledge
> - Delivering mutual benefit
>     through knowledge sharing

Is either version better structured than the other?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is better as it introduces the idea of sharing (which seems to be one of the main concepts earlier in the sentence, whereas in the second sentence it appears tacked on as an afterthought. 
That is, assuming the main point you are trying to convey is the benefit of sharing, rather than the benefit of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The first is more eloquent, yet the second is more common especially in business and organisational contexts. We always hear and talk about knowledge sharing to enhance performance.

Comment: Wouldn't  that be "knowledge sharing for performance enhancement"? :)

Comment: This is correct too :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the first version, *sharing of knowledge*.

*knowledge sharing* reminds me of some political/religious speeches.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use the *second* version.

As such *knowledge sharing* and *sharing of knowledge* mean exactly the same, just like:

> mind reading - reading of minds
>   water purification - purification of water

However, as you can see in those two examples, water purification and mind reading are more commonly used to express the combination as a whole.

Looking at the rest of your sentence, and your description (documentation of a major project), I would think that *knowledge sharing* is a recognizable and understandable *concept* in the field, and I would see no reason not to use it.

If you are writing for a more general audience, I would advice the bit more down-to-earth, more explicative *sharing of knowledge*.
In that case, I would also advice against the use of business jargon like "delivering mutual benefit" though!

So in short: for a general audience with no knowledge of business or project jargon:

> All involved will benefit from the project because of sharing of knowledge.

For a business audience:

> The project will deliver mutual benefits through knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the expression 'knowledge sharing' has a specific definition.

***[knowledge sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_Sharing)***

> Knowledge Sharing is an activity through which knowledge (i.e., information, skills, or expertise) is exchanged among people, friends, families, communities …

Use the expression when you mean exactly that, and the phrase 'sharing of knowledge' in a more general or broader/narrower sense.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same there is no difference between them.